# How to change the title of page dynamically with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

Im using Twig for template in my website, I extend `layout.html.twig` in all my others twig pages,so In my `layout.html.twig` I have the title of page :

```
<title>{% block title %}Title of my website{% endblock %}</title>
```

Now my problem is how to change this title dynamically in all my pages, for example I have `news.html.twig` to show all latest news in the world, so I hope when I display my news page I have the title of the news in my title of page...

```
<title>{% block title %}Title of the news{% endblock %}</title>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are close. In your `news.html.twig` I assume you have all of your content in a block like this:

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block content %}
    content of the news page here
{% endblock %}`
```

So all you have to do is add another block for the title **outside** of that content block

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Title of news page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    content of the news page here
{% endblock %}`
```

Answer (score 29):

My solution looks a bit more elegant in the child-templates:

In your `layout.html.twig`:

```
<title>{% if page_title is defined %} {{ page_title }} | {% endif %} Your Website</title>
```

In your child page-templates:

```
{% extends '::layout.html.twig' %}

{% set page_title = 'Your page-title' %}

{# Put the rest of your page below #}
```

And you can also reuse the title in eg. an  doing `<h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>` :-)

Comment: You should place the dash (or any other delimiter) inside the conditional block, like that: {% if page_title is defined %} {{ page_title }} - {% endif %}Your Website. Otherwise, if page_title is undefined you would get trailing delimiter before your base title.

Comment: It's a bit more elegant, as it provides a default title.

Comment: Another benefit is you can reuse this variable, i.e. `<h1>{{ page_title }}</h1>`.

Answer (score 7):

Is more simple that you imagine.

Put on main/parent layout

```
...
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My Site</title>
...
```

and, in a content page ( on child layout ), get the page title

```
...
<h1>{{ block('title') }}</h1>
...
```

So, any title that you put in head title will be displayed in the content title.

Answer (score 0):

{% block title %} {{ post.title }}Symfony web.app{% endblock %}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the existing answers this question already has, so that it is useful to users with similar issues.